# Listview with big image is very slow

Tags: android, listview, caching, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am working on an Android App. The app has a listview that each item contains a image to show. One screen can contain around 3 images normally. I am testing with some real camera captured uncompressed images, each of them around 1.5M or so. It turns out the scroll is really slow and stuck. I was wondering is this because of the Android OS implementation, or did I have wrong usage?

Here's detail:

In the Listview, I have a ViewHolder to keep all item instance so it will be faster than doing `findViewById`. At the time this listview's activity load, I will spin a couple of image loader AsyncTasks to help load the image. My image loader is implement as a singleton and have two-level caches. The first level cache is a `Map` of `SoftReference`:

```
private Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> l1ImageCache = 
        new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();
```

and the L2 cache is a cache folder. If cache couldn't hit, the code will do async download and update the view. The whole LoadImage code path is in my AsyncTask implementation and apart of the UI thread.

The issue is, seems like cache works fine, and image loading is pretty fast (takes around 10 ms to load from memory), but the scroll is still stuck.

```
12-15 21:56:46.622: I/Choreographer(5803): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

If I change the images from 1M each to 100K each, the image view became very smooth.

I was wondering if this is a OS limitation? or could there be anything that is wrong?

Comment: Load bitmap using asynctask

Comment: Try to use universal image loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: cant you scale the images before adding them to list view??

Comment: Have you checked Bitmap allocation or Managing memory of bitmaps, if not, please check this video and code below the Android developer video:  "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8".

Comment: use lazy loader example https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: @Arju Hi, thank you for advice, but please refer to my post that I mentioned I already used AsyncTask

Comment: If you did image loading in doInBackground in won't report the mainthread problem. You are doing some heavy tasks in main thread

Comment: @Arju Is there a good way to debug which part in the code could cause this? because as far as I understand my code, there's nothing but just assignment on the UI thread.. All image seeking and downloading are in AsyncTask

Comment: Can you post the whole log? and  just asking which adapter you are using? Since the code is looping its difficult to debug point by point

Answer (score 1):

This warning means that your code is taking to much processing time/memory and therefore Android skips **roughly** speaking several calculations (frames). What you are doing may prevent older Smartphones to execute your code. For a solution you should move the critical parts of the UI thread using AsynTasks as already stated by Arju. A very good introduction can be found [here (Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently)](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html). Especially as you state that you are currently rendering "uncompressed real camera captured images" you should carefully read the part [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). There you will see that the actual memory allocation of such images is much bigger then you think. Last but not least if you still facing performance issues read [Making ListView Scrolling Smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html).

I would argue to get familiar with these issues before using 3rd party libs like LazyList or the Android Universal Image Loader.

Comment: Hi, thank you for advice, but please refer to my post that I mentioned I already used AsyncTask. I have verified the time to "get" the bitmap is like 10ms each, and since it is under async, it doesn't look like to be the issue of the Lag.

Comment: I'm sorry. My failure. However, why you are applying the AsyncTask as a Singleton? Would that not indicate a sequential loading of the images instead of parallel processing? Normally you would hold a weak reference to the ImageView you want to fill and before starting a new AsyncTask you would check if there is already one working for this ImageView ([Handle Concurrency](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html#concurrency)). I'm not sure if this works with the ViewHolder as well. :/